# Is it necessary to pass the file pointer to main?

Tags: c

I am quite new to C programming and I have to make a program that asks the user to enter the file name to open and then open that file and print the values sorted.

Will I need to pass the file pointer to main, or can I just open the file in one function and I can work with the file throughout the other functions?

```
int getFile ()
{
    char file_name[100]; 
    FILE* fp;           
    int rc;              
    printf("Enter the file name: ");
    rc = scanf("%s", file_name);
    if (rc != 1)
        printf ("error");

    fp = fopen(file_name, "r");

    return 0;

}
```

Do I have to pass the file pointer from here to main?

Comment: Have you tried either? It would be easier to help specifically if you try one and find a problem.

Comment: Do you have to pass a file pointer to the library methods you call? If so, then the file pointer needs to be available where you call those methods.

Comment: If I enter a filename over 99 characters, your program starts to fail. Keep that in mind. Looks like all you need to do is return the file pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pass the file name as an argument to `main` function, it maybe what you want.
You might use `int main(int argc, char* argv[])`, an example:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    FILE*  fp;
    if (argc == 1)
        printf("usage : a.out filename\n");
    else
    {
        if (fp = fopen(*++argv, "r") != NULL)
        {
            /*your code here*/
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If he's new to C programming (and since he didn't specify a platform, or build environment), you might explain why you have used "a.out" in the printf usage line.

Comment: @RandyHoward Yes, you may also help me improve my answer,or just edit it.

Answer (score 0):

You can open the file in one function and pass it as argument to other functions. For example, for the pre-open file handle stdin, you could use it as:

```
char mystring [100];
fgets (mystring , 100 , pFile)
```